# Is there an updated method for running scripts with python variables in Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Before we could run a script this way

```
script = 'script.py'

!python '$script'
```

However, recently, this error occurs

```
python3: can't open file '$script': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Is there an updated way to run a script with python variables  in colab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow,

```
!python '$script'
```

Is working again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead.

```
!python {script}
```